# Как получить объект по ссылке в УФ?

Tags: 1с, формы

Реально надо. Есть на форме таблица с документами по текущему выбранному элементу. И есть блок где по этот документ редактировать или новый создавать и редактировать и потом сохранять. То есть по любому нужен реквизит ДокНорм типа справочникОбъект. Но как сделать чтобы загрузить в ДокНорм объект из таблицы документов по текущему (там ссылка на справочник)?

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ОткрытьДокументНормирования(_ДСЕ)    
    Если Элементы.ЭлементыНормирования.ТекущиеДанные<>Неопределено Тогда
        Если ЗначениеЗаполнено(Элементы.ЭлементыНормирования.ТекущиеДанные.Документ) Тогда             
             ДокументНормирования = _ПолучитьОбъект(Элементы.ЭлементыНормирования.ТекущиеДанные.Документ);            
        КонецЕсли;
    КонецЕсли;

КонецПроцедуры


&НаСервере
Функция _ПолучитьОбъект(_Ссылка)
    Возврат _Ссылка.ПолучитьОбъект();
КонецФункции
```

Выдает ошибку. Как быть?

Comment: *Выдает ошибку. Как быть?* Ну как минимум процитировать сообщение об ошибке, с точным указанием места (строка кода) и времени (ввод, рантайм) её возникновения - простой констатации недостаточно. PS. Искренне порадовала "ссылка в ультрафиолете".

Comment: На форме нужно хранить Ссылку на объект; А если нужно в самом объекте что-то править, то как написали ниже в ответе, - при клике на Ссылку (на форме) Открываем форму через ОткрытьЗначение(СсылкаНаОбъект);

Answer (score 0):

Простой вариант - использовать методы ОткрытьЗначение или ПоказатьЗначение.

СсылкаНаОбъект = Элементы.ЭлементыНормирования.ТекущиеДанные.Документ;

ОткрытьЗначение(СсылкаНаОбъект);
// Если для конфигурации свойство РежимИспользованияМодальности установлено в НеИспользовать
// ПоказатьЗначение(, СсылкаНаОбъект);

Можно использовать параметры открытия формы.

ПараметрыФормы = Новый Структура("Ключ", СсылкаНаОбъект);
ОткрытьФорму("Документ.ДокументНормирования.ФормаОбъекта", ПараметрыФормы);